# Where can I find a very broad Drupal tutorial?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

There are tons of Drupal tutorials out there - theming, modules, database interaction, taxonomy, etc. etc. Most that I find are extremely in-depth, but none give a big-picture, site-level overview.

Are there any good tutorials (videos and/or text-based) that show the creation of a simple website, with a simple administrative section? Not ridiculous reams of configuration, or complex, arcane modules...just a simple website with basic pages (i.e. about us, people, news, etc.) that are admin-configurable, and that doesn't look like the default Drupal install.

Obviously to be an effective Drupal dev, I would need to learn these ins and outs, and I certainly plan to. What I need right now though is enough of an overview to give a presentation on Drupal in several days to non-technical people on how we can use Drupal to architect their website. I've already purchased Pro Drupal 7 Development, and have perused the Drupal API docs and tutorials on their website, but these are all too micro - where's the macro?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the book [Using Drupal](http://www.usingdrupal.com/) is a good start for you. It's less about "How does this dark corner of the API work?" but more about tasks you need to accomplish when building a certain type of site (a blog, a wiki, an online store...).

Comment: That was the first book I read whenlearning drupal 6. I still use it to look up small things. It's very good, and gives you the needed overview, before you can dive deeper into Drupal. I haven't read the book for version 7 yet, but if they keep the same standard, it's a must have book.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started....

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmRW7FALA88

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IT_TZEQEm5c

Creating a Content Type

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElXXz9-bxJc